# Search function xml xpath with variable that contains apostrophe

Tags: xml, variables, search, xpath, apostrophe

I have made a search function to search products from a XML file.

The problem is, I have XML content that contains an apostrophe ' .
When I search with the keyword accu's I get no results because the apostrophe.

This is the xpath I use to gather my results:

$products = $xml->xpath("//products[contains(.,\"$keyword\")]");

$keyword different every time, depends where you search on.

My xml looks like this:

```
<products>
        <hoofdgroep>Gereedschappen</hoofdgroep>
        <subgroep>Accugereedschap</subgroep>
        <artikelgroep>Accu's voor accugereedschap</artikelgroep>
        <artikelnummer>224975</artikelnummer>
        <artikelnaam>accu bosch  9.6V 2.0ah</artikelnaam>
        <merk>Bosch</merk>
        <eenheid>st</eenheid>
</products>
```

Please help!

Comment: What programming language/library are you using here?  The best approach to this problem is to use a fixed XPath expression that includes an XPath variable, and then supply the value for that variable using whatever mechanism your library provides.  Simply concatenating unknown strings together is to invite the XPath equivalent of SQL injection attacks...

Comment: It's a PHP search script for a webshop. Customers need to search products that are stored into an XML library.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is totally fine. You must add some escaping or something else before sending the query, for example to `accu\'s`, or not using another character either in the search keyword or document. Quotes, accents and apostrophes are often mixed up.

Do not forget to consider quoting the double backslash to prevent injection attacks! By the way, XPath allows both single and double quotes for strings, so you could also use single quotes inside instead of escaped double quotes.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't get it to work with \'s, so I found an other solution. 

I just remove the 's from the keyword. Now it find the product without problems.

$keyword = str_replace("'s","",$keyword);

Well, I've found another problem, when the keyword has mixed cases, for example AcCu, I get no results because it seems to be case-sensitive...

Comment: You can use `translate` to somewhat convert capitalization within XPath 1.0 (yet it is hard to provide unicode support using that). There are lots of question on exactly this matter. PHP also allows to register and use PHP functions which might be more appropriate. I guess there are appropriate question on that too, otherwise you might ask it as a new one.